# How to use two way binding on SQL Server CE database windows phone 8

Tags: c#, sql, windows-phone-8, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to update some sample database from this article : 
http://erikej.blogspot.com/2013/04/generate-windows-phone-8-local-database.html

Following the article I have everything to connect to the database. Now I want to be able to edit database columns.

What I thought was to change the textblock to textbox and change binding to two ways binding
but apparently it's wrong or maybe not enough

I was told by Mr erikej to call `submitchanges`

and I did it, but it seems like it's not being called where or when it should be.

Any help would be appreciated.

Xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="MainLongListSelector" Margin="0,0,-12,0" >
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                  <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17">
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Zip}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                      <TextBox Text="{Binding City,Mode=TwoWay}"  Margin="12,-6,12,0" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsProvince,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
        <Button Name="save" Tap="save_Tap">

        </Button>
```

CS code

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
        using (hesabContext ctx = new hesabContext(hesabContext.ConnectionString))
        {
            ctx.CreateIfNotExists();
            ctx.LogDebug = true;
            MainLongListSelector.ItemsSource = ctx.Hesabdar.ToList();
        }
}

private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
}

private void save_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
        using (hesabContext ctx = new hesabContext(hesabContext.ConnectionString))
        {
            ctx.SubmitChanges();
        }
}
```

Comment: You need to keep your DataContext alive for the duration of your form to do this.

Comment: ok i added the database creation to app.xaml.cs ! <br/>
added database connection code before the page constructor!! <br/>
and now it's working <br/>
i know i may be doing it the worse way possible but it's working <br/>
Thank you

Comment: Yes, really you should be using MVVM, but glad it worked for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep your DataContext alive for the duration of your form to do this.